# Different X axis scale based on user parameter

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to make a dashboard where the user can select the X axis scale using a parameter.

So if they choose "month" then the X axis is broken down by month as per below

```
tilldevicedata
| where todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc) between (_startTime.._endTime)
| where Brand has_any (_brand)
| where Country == _country
| where Store has_any (_store)
| summarize TotalSales = sum(TransactionValueGross) by monthofyear(todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc))
```

If they choose week then I want the breakdown to be by weekofyear instead of monthofyear

How can I make that part of the query conditional based on a user parameter in the Data Explorer dashboard?

-- EDIT --

I tried to make it dynamic but I only got monthofyear, it never hits dayofyear and I dont understand why

```
let _timePeriodInHours = datetime_diff("Hour", _startTime, _endTime);

    tilldevicedata
    | where todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc) between (_startTime.._endTime)
    | where Brand has_any (_brand)
    | where Country == _country
    | where Store has_any (_store)
    | summarize TotalSales = sum(TransactionValueGross) by case(_timePeriodInHours < 1, monthofyear(todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc)), _timePeriodInHours > 1, dayofyear(todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc)), _timePeriodInHours)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample query

Note the use of `summarize ... by case(...)`**

```
range i from 1 to 10000 step 1    
| extend dttm = ago(1000d * rand())
| summarize count() by case(_period == 'month', startofmonth(dttm), _period == 'week', startofweek(dttm), datetime(null))
| render timechart
```

**_period parameter definition**

[image: _period parameter definition]

**Week**

[image: week]

**Month**

[image: month]

Comment: works perfectly, could this be automated based on the TimeRange parameter like if TimeRange is < 1d then breakdown by hours, if TimeRange > 1d and < 1m then break down by day

Comment: I edited my query to clarify a little I might have misstated what I meant by a variable hope the edit clarifies

Comment: done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72171369/how-to-format-the-x-axis-nicer